# MyEclipse blue 2013 SR1 crashes on startup when no Internet connection

Tags: java, apache, jsp, struts2, myeclipse

I have issues with MyEclipse BLUE 2013 SR1 for STRUTS2 when I try to launch it and I have no Internet connection. There are quite a few times when I am traveling and in an area where there is not a free WiFi hotspot around and I am trying to get some work done on a project - but I can't since MyEclipse crashes on start-up and gives me a dialog box pointing to a log file.

A copy of the log-file when this happens follows below:

```
SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd:1:2
```

if internet is working project is working but without internet it is not loading ..Dispatcher initialization failed

**Update**

my java web project is not loading and showing following error if i disable my int

> SEVERE: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed. at (-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN:1:2)
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
>
> SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
>   Unable to load configuration. - http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd:1:2
>
> SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
>   Unable to load configuration. - http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd:1:2

Comment: because you are using `http://` protocol, change it to `file://` and you don't need it at all.

Comment: may be you're using some kind of internet dependency or some code that require things from internet. One of my clients download files from FTP on app startup.

Answer (score 0):

Umesh,

Having it crash on startup because there is no Internet connection is certainly unexpected and unusual.

1) By crash, do you mean that the workbench itself refuses to load or do you simply see an error message and can continue to use the IDE?
2) I'm assuming your Struts configuration file had been left open in the workspace when this happens?

We'll specifically try to test this case ourselves and let you know if we need more information. For direct support, do consider posting on the MyEclipse forums as well - http://myeclipseide.com/forums

Best,
Brian.